# Can't run JavaScript on web browser address bar?

Tags: javascript

According to this video (1:45), the following JavaScript alert works on web browser by simply typing it on address bar.

```
javascript: alert("Hello World")
```

[Check the link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9L9J3JVhJL8&list=PL_c9BZzLwBRLVh9OdCBYFEql6esA6aRsi&index=4)

However, instead of getting pop up message (Hello World), my web browser has redirected it to google search.

I've tried with different web browser but still doesn't get the pop up.

What is the issue in this case and how to solve it?

Comment: If see the video with accuracy, He is doing like this:
`javascript: alert("Hello World")`

Comment: Yeah, that's true, but I still don't get a pop up, instead browser redirected it to google search.

Comment: @Wolf Are you copy-pasting it?

Comment: @ShivamSingla, I've typed it manually & also copy paste but still doesn't work

Answer (score 2):

You need to instruct the browser to execute your command as JS:

```js
javascript:alert('Is this 1998?')
```

Keep in mind that if you copy & paste this directly into your browser it will be rendered as `alert('Is this 1998?')` for security reasons. You don't want to execute arbitrary JS code you pick over the internet.